# How to accept plain text in a route handler

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hapi.js, filepond

I'm using [FilePond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/) to upload files to a hapi.js 17.9 API. FilePond allows automatic uploads after a user selects a file, and has a UI for deleting/reverting/undoing an uploaded file. Per FilePond's documentation...

*FilePond sends DELETE request with 12345 as body by tapping the undo button*

Where *12345* is an ID supplied by the server when the file was uploaded. Note this is not JSON, it's a plain text body.

I have a hapi.js route that's set up to handle DELETE methods, with the default validation settings. When FilePond sends it's request, Hapi responds with a 400 error before my handler code executes, and prints this message in the console:

```
Validation-failAction:error ValidationError: "value" must be an object
    at Object.exports.process (/home/lamont/projects/rooster/api/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/joi/lib/errors.js:203:19)
    at internals.Object._validateWithOptions (/home/lamont/projects/rooster/api/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/joi/lib/types/any/index.js:764:31)
    at module.exports.internals.Any.root.validate (/home/lamont/projects/rooster/api/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/joi/lib/index.js:147:23)
    at Object.internals.input (/home/lamont/projects/rooster/api/node_modules/hapi/lib/validation.js:83:63)
    at exports.payload (/home/lamont/projects/rooster/api/node_modules/hapi/lib/validation.js:50:22)
    at Request._lifecycle (/home/lamont/projects/rooster/api/node_modules/hapi/lib/request.js:263:62)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

The hapi docs strongly imply the [default payload validation options](https://hapijs.com/api/17.9.0#-routeoptionsvalidatepayload) don't do any payload validation, so I'm a little surprised that this scenario is even a problem.

I've tried the following:

`options.payload= {parse: false}`

`options.payload= {allow: "text\*"}`

`options.validate= { payload: async (v, o) => { return v } }`

`options.validate= { payload: true }`

`options.validate= { payload: false }`

`options.validate= undefined`

`options.validate= null`

Edit:
Based on the suggestion of one of the guys on my team, I've also tried

`options.validate : { payload: (() => { return Joi.string(); })() }`

and defining my route options with no validate property at all (which ought to be functionally equivalent to an explicit undefined but who knows).

In all these cases, I still get the above validation error. Is it just not possible to write a hapi route that accepts plain, non-json text?

Comment: I'm not sure. What I do know is that a DELETE request having a body is not accepted everywhere so you could try to change the http method type for the remove call and see if that makes a difference.